# Does My imposed Condition have a name in category theory/Set theory?

Tags: scala, math, types, category-theory, set-theory

There's a requirement i'm placing on the signature of a **total & referencially transparent** function:

```scala
def add[T](a: T)(b: T): T
//requirement is type T under e.g. addition must always bear antoher type T
// and is not allowed to throw runtime arithmetic exceptions or such.
```

this requirement can be easily fulfilled for many types such as `Int`,`String`,`Nat`(natural numbers); yet is also easily violated by types such as `NonZeroInt` as addition of two non-zero integers can in fact be zero.

My question is there a coined term for this condition? Monoid comes to mind but it's obvious I'm not imposing all the rules for monoids here.

Comment: AFAIK, referential transparency is a term coined by programming language theory, as neither Set Theory nor Category Theory have the notion of "effects" as part of their definitions, it is a property of a program in a programming language. Having said that, a total function *is a* mathematical function, as all functions (unless explicitly declared as partial, i.e. given a function X -> Y we declare a partial function X' -> Y where X' is a subset of X) are total.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah maybe I wrote that part a little hastily. I've looked up they say that if a function in your programming language throws an exception it's not total that means it doesn't bear a result for all the set of inputs that it takes. also if it throws an exception it's no longer referencially transparent as you can't replace this function application with it's result value all the time.

Comment: Exactly, so you're requiring totality from your function, you want it to be equivalent to a mathematical total function.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov So what should I call a type T that the defined addition function for which is a mathematical total function?

Comment: `T` is a type parameter, not sure it matters what you call it. What you want to do, perhaps, is require an implicit evidence that `T` is total. But then, still, someone can pass evidence which "cheat" you and don't provide a total function.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov referential transparency if from Russel/Whitehead's work and adopted by philosophy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency#History.

Comment: @shayan I think the name for your function as Yuval says is "function", you really want to qualify it then it is "total function". But totality, I far as I know, there aren't tools to verify functional totality in Scala at compile time. If you interest in the subject goes beyond Scala suggest looking into Idris https://www.idris-lang.org/, where this property in tracked by the type system (other similar languages are Agda and Coq, but I find idris way more approachable).

Comment: @pedrofurla Good to know, thx for the reference

Comment: @pedrofurla: "But totality, I far as I know, there aren't tools to verify functional totality in Scala at compile time." – Another name for "verify totality" is "prove termination", which Alan Turing has a thing or two to say about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, then the term you are looking for is "closure" for a set given an operation.  Refer to the mathematical definition in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)).  In short:

> A set has closure under an operation if performance of that operation
>   on members of the set always produces a member of the same set

However, "closure" seems to have a different meaning in computer science.  See the link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  And my searches pertaining to closure in the context of Scala, even when also putting it in the context of mathematics or set-theory, doesn't lead to any helpful results.  Perhaps this is why you've had trouble finding the coined term.

Answer (score 0):

Without any laws required it is just anot operation on a set T, nothing more. If `add` is associative you can call it Semigroup.